# Java adding arraylist to object? "Flight Check In Exercise"

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm new to Java and have received a task by my teacher that I cannot solve myself yet.
This is the task:

Passengers at Gate 
Implement two classes Passenger and Flight which simulate the situation at a gate at the airport.
Passenger holds data on each passenger (name, status, etc.).
Flight has the data of the flight and the list of passengers (and if the passenger has checked in). 
The application can show:

- List of passengers who have boarded.
- List of passengers who have only checked-in.
- List of passengers who are no-shows (they didn’t check in).

The user can then change the status of a passenger from checked-in to boarded. 
Hint: work with a collection class (ArrayList or Vector) to deal with several objects.

I have created my Passenger objects. How do I now create flight objects that contain my passenger arraylist? I found nothing helpful on Google so far.

Here's a look at my amateur code. Any help is much appreciated

```
public class Passenger {
        String name;
        String status;

    public Passenger(String name){
        this.name=name;
        status = "no-show";

    }

    public void checkIn(){
        status = "checked-in";
    }

    public void boarded(){
        status = "boarded";
    }
}

public class PassengerAtGate {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        Passenger pass1 = new Passenger("Heinz Müller");
        Passenger pass2 = new Passenger("Max Mustermann");
        Passenger pass3 = new Passenger("Barbara Beispiel");


    }
}
```

Comment: Did you look at the javadocs for ArrayList ?  See any interestingly named methods ?

Comment: *I found nothing helpful on Google so far* - I think you have to actually click on the results

Comment: @ScaryWombat The problem is I don't really know which keywords to google for

Comment: It is written in your question as a Hint - ArrayList - Millions of examples

Answer (score -1):

Hope it is pretty straight-forward, and the below implementation helps

```
public class Passenger {
    String name;
    String status;

    public Passenger(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        status = "no-show";

    }

    public void checkIn() {
        status = "checked-in";
    }

    public void boarded() {
        status = "boarded";
    }
}

public class Flight {
    String flightNum;
    String source;
    String destination;
    List < Passenger > passengers;

    Flight(String flightNum, String source, String destination) {
        this.flightNum = flightNum;
        this.source = source;
        this.destination = destination;
        this.passengers = new ArrayList < > ();
    }
    public List < Passenger > getPassengers() {
        return this.passengers;
    }
}

public class PassengerAtGate {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        Passenger pass1 = new Passenger("Heinz Müller");
        Passenger pass2 = new Passenger("Max Mustermann");
        Passenger pass3 = new Passenger("Barbara Beispiel");

        Flight flight = new Flight("AB-001","Bangalore","Delhi");
        flight.getPassengers().add(pass1);
        flight.getPassengers().add(pass2);
        flight.getPassengers().add(pass3);

    }
}
```

Comment: That looks promising. I will try to implement this. Thank you

Comment: Glad that it could help. Please do accept the answer if it has solved your usecase. Thanks.